# Best practise how to sync a SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, synchronization, cluster-computing, database-replication, failover

What is best practise if we have application using a SQL Server database and we would like to have backup if SQL Server not work?

Our scenario:

1. We would like to use a SQL Server database (main).
2. If main SQL Server does not work, we would like to use different SQL Server database with same data.
3. If main SQL Server works again, we need to sync data back to main SQL Server database.

Failover Cluster is an option, but are they any other options?

Comment: This is really not programming related and should be asked on [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com) where all the DBA's hang out - you'll get much more and better answers there! Voting to move...

Comment: This is a very broad question.  Have you checked out http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic?

Comment: You are looking for the concept of High Availability.  You can use Google, or can check out what [Microsoft says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190202(v=sql.105).aspx).